# How to allow multiple different lengths for strings in XSD?

Tags: xml, xsd

So I have a custom data type:

```
<xs:simpleType name="AbbreviatedTeamName">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:length value="3"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

I would like to have either 3 or 0 to be valid in the

```
    <xs:length value="3"/>
```

such as:

```
    <xs:length value="3" or value="0"/>
```

But I am unsure of how to do this or if this is even possible.

Comment: Do you mean the length from 0 to 3? Or exactly either 0 or 3, but not both?

Comment: @Nurzhan 0 or 3 but not both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use`xs:pattern` to specify a regular expression that restricts a string to be 0 or 3 characters long:

```
  <xs:simpleType name="AbbreviatedTeamName">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="|..."/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
```